# Find label of a city in OSM map

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, nominatim

I would like to know if it is possible to find label of the beginning of a village, city or town? 
I mean if there is some difference in 2 points, one 100 meters before the mark and the other 100 meters after the mark so that I know which one is in the city (even though there would be inaccuracy of one "way" segment)...

I tried to find difference in tags. In some cases I found that the mark is precisely between 2 ways but in another case the mark is in the middle of a way and even though I was not able to identify change between segment out of city and in the city (tag "place" doesn't create boundary of the city in terms of these marks but rather cadastral boundary)....

Thanks for any help

Comment: Not a programming question. Try http://help.openstreetmap.org/ instead. Also, it is not quite clear which "label" you are talking about. Adding a photo will help.

Comment: But it has something to do with algorithmization so that I created a post here